# How can I create a self-portrait time-lapse montage?

Tags: timelapse, self-portrait

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I hold my face in the same place for a month long daily self-portrait?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/16469/how-can-i-hold-my-face-in-the-same-place-for-a-month-long-daily-self-portrait)

I'm aiming for something like Noah Kalina and others have and are creating, and apps and programs like "everyday" offer, although i'd like to do it myself, without such aid. For the last couple of weeks I've just been using my  my point and shoot camera, and the main problem is that my face is in a different place in all of the photos. How can I line it up in the exact same place for every photo? Also, how am I supposed to hold the exact same expression for every photo.

Answer (score 2):

1. Put the camera on a tripod or some other support, make sure the tripod is exactly in the same location every day (making a mark on the floor with some tape can help)
2. Stand in exactly the same place everyday (again, some tape on the floor can help)
3. About the expression, experiment, try to find the most "repeatable" expression for you (smile 3 times in a row, then make a natural face 3 times in a row...)

Answer (score 2):

Place a mirror behind the camera and draw a large oval on the mirror so you can line yourself up carefully with this guideline. Pick an expression that is very simple, e.g. mouth shut with slight smile.